# Best way to plot histogram or any other graphical interpretation

Tags: r, histogram

I have csv file with following data set:

```
gv,ca,level1,2
gv,bg,level1,1
zea,li,level1,1
zea,li,level3,1
zea,de,level1,26
zea,de,level3,5
zea,el,level1,1
zea,eo,level1,3
zea,en,level1,5
zea,en,level2,34
zea,en,level3,38
zea,en,level4,12
zea,es,level1,7
zea,la,level1,7
zea,zea,level1,5
zea,zea,level3,4
zea,stq,level1,1
zea,sk,level2,1
zea,nl,level4,4
zea,fr,level2,9
zea,fy,level2,1
cdo,cdo,level3,1
cdo,de,level1,23
cdo,de,level2,4
cdo,de,level3,4
cdo,eo,level1,1
cdo,eo,level2,1
cdo,eo,level3,3
cdo,en,level1,6
cdo,en,level2,31
cdo,en,level3,38
cdo,en,level4,17
cdo,es,level1,8
cdo,es,level2,6
cdo,es,level3,3
cdo,fr,level1,14
```

I want to build a histogram but some how the second column need to be incorporated in the histogram, the way you read the data is example: In gv we have two users with with ca experience level1, similarly in gv we have 1 user with bg experience level 1.

I know how to build histograms in R but I am trying rap around this thought in my head and trying to figure how to get this in to a graphical representation.

Comment: It's a little unclear what you want to do... Can you edit your Q to include an image or link to an example of your desired output?

Answer (score 0):

Like @Ben said, it is a little difficult to see what you're getting at here. You may need to reformat your data so that you have only have only one type of data (class) per table.